# Is that right asymptotic formula?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Is it correct asymptotic formula: $ \ln {n^2 \choose n} \sim n\ln{n} $

Comment: Found answer - that was correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\log \left(\binom{n^2}{n}\right)=\log\left(\frac{(n^2)!}{n!(n^2-n)!}\right)=\log((n^2)!)-\log(n!)-\log((n^2-n)!)$$ Now, use Stirling approximation $$\log(m!)=m (\log (m)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   (m)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)$$ Apply it to each term and simplify.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the same approach.

Comment: You are welcome ! When I see a factorial,I immediately think about Stirling.